# javascript render function for objects with missing properties

Tags: javascript, object, jsx

Our contact record has a phones object, which has 13 possible sub-objects corresponding to the following phone types:

```
      personalMobile1,
      personalMobile2,
      personalMobile3,
      workMobile1,
      workMobile2,
      workMobile3,
      homePhone1,
      homePhone2,
      homePhone3,
      workPhone1,
      workPhone2,
      workPhone3,
      workFax1
```

I'm trying to write a render function, that will output only numbers (e.g. mobilePhone1.number) which are defined.

Many of these sub-objects may not be present on the returned contact object. This is the maximal possible object.

Suppose I just have 2 sub-objects, then I want output like this:

```
<p> +91 9883727387 </p>
<p> +91 9736551225 </p>
```

Comment: do you have any code, or do you think you've reached icanhazcode.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
If (mobilePhone.hasOwnProperty("number")) {
    // do something here...
}
```

You can use these sort of conditions within ***jsx*** render functions by simply using the ***&&*** notation

```
MobilePhone.hasOwnProperty && 
<React-component />
```

You may be looping through a bunch of contacts, so here is an example:

```
Contacts.map(function (contactObj) {
   If (contactObj.hasOwnProperty("number") {
      Return <p> { contactObj.number } </p> 
   }
});
```